# Override inventory checks when creating an order in Magento

Tags: magento, inventory, orders

Is there a way to force Magento to add an item to an order even if it is out of stock and the configuration is set to track stock and not allow backorders? In other words, I want to be able to create an order programmatically with items on it and I don't want it to fail no matter the status of the items inventory and the settings in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: You need to Override some methods in **Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item**.
You want `checkQty()` and `checkQuoteItemQty()`

Exactly what changes to make depend on exactly how you want to implement the modification, also depends on whether you stock non-simple products.

A simple edit would just set `checkQty()`'s return value to true and return `$result` in `checkQuoteItemQty()` before

```
 if ($this->getMinSaleQty() && $qty < $this->getMinSaleQty()) {
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks SH. Something I failed to mention in my question is that I don't want this to happen all the time so overriding the default Mage behavior isn't a good option for me. I was hoping there was a way to force an out of stock item onto an order. I believe the admin panel does this but I can't determine how.

Comment: I worked with this logic about 2 weeks ago. If I remember correctly, `checkQuoteItemQty()` does checks for `isAdmin`. Look for that and try and replicate the behavior with the check for the situation you want to allow ordering in.
Though it sounds like you really want to do is to extend the backorder functionality, too be conditional.